# While using useState hook and onClick event in react I get error when calling the function in onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [fruit, setFruit ] = useState("apple")

  function settingFruit_1()
  {
    setFruit("mango");
  }

  return ( 
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>{fruit}</h1>
      //why am I getting the error when calling the function like this onClick = {settingFruit_1()}
      <button onClick = {settingFruit_1()}> submit </button> 
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the error that I see:

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
    at renderWithHooks (<anonymous>:11510:25)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (<anonymous>:14733:23)
    at beginWork (<anonymous>:15659:24)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (<anonymous>:3454:24)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (<anonymous>:3479:26)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (<anonymous>:3513:41)
    at beginWork$1 (<anonymous>:18904:17)
    at performUnitOfWork (<anonymous>:18371:22)
    at workLoopSync (<anonymous>:18308:15)
```

Comment: replace `settingFruit_1()` with `settingFruit_1`

Comment: I know the solution but I am not able to understand why it has to be written like this onClick = {settingFruit_1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are invoking the function rather than passing it's reference to the `onClick` handler

```
<button onClick = {settingFruit_1}> submit </button> // only pass reference without the ()
```

2. Why does this cause infinite rerenders? Because by invoking function directly, you are calling the functions directly, rather than calling after click. This causes rerender => component is set again => function invoked again => setFruits => rerender => .........

Answer (score 1):

onClick Function expects you to pass a reference to the callback that it executes when user click that button. But here you call that function in onClick.

**Solution:**

Try using below syntax:

`<button onClick={settingFruit_1}>submit</button>`